# After set "include " property in tsconfig.json, i get error

Tags: typescript

I add include in my tsconfig.json.[tsconfig.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s61O4.png), this is my .d.ts [typing file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHqE6.png),
this is my directory structure [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Rlx.png), i had add `declare module '*.less';` in my file, but i also can get a error in vscode in file `src/pages/index.tsx` [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyM7b.png)

Comment: if i removde "include" property the error will disappear

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a `.less` file with TypeScript. You need a bundler like wepback to handle importing styles, images, e.t.c.

Comment: thanks, i am using `webpack` and try to use `css module` so i get this error

Comment: Where's your `webpack.config.js` file? It's supposed to be in the project root.